# Generate Random Date in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm new to groovy and I'd like to know how to generate random dates in groovy, in a specific range. Let's say from June 2013 to June 2014.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(new Date()..new Date(2014-1900,5,1)).toList().sort{Math.random()}[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider this:

```
​def dateA = Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy", "01-06-2013")
int range = 365
def randomInterval = new Random().nextInt(range)
def dateB = dateA.plus(randomInterval)

println dateA
println dateB
```

Note that this does not account for leap years.

Comment: ErEcTus, if this helps you, please consider accepting the answer. Tim, noted... will take into consideration.